# Timetable for event.

Tags: 7, views

i'm trying to create a timetable using Drupal 7. I need this timetable for an event.

At the moment I created it throught views but I think it is too much "heavy".

I did it in this way.

I created 3 content types: Speaker, Company and Agenda.
In the Agenda content type I've got the node reference fields pointing to Speaker and Company.
The event has got 3 streams.
Now I'm managing the display throught the views, I've created a basic page with a table and per each row (time) I've put one view (content) which shows 3 nodes (one per each stream).
this is a normal view wich shows title and body of the node.
To show the speaker and the company I've created another view (fields) with agenda nid such as contextual filter. I've put it inside agenda--node.tpl.php.
Then I've put another view inside agenda--node.tpl.php which create a js dialog with the topic, speaker and company info.
Basically we have in one page about 70 views...

Is it heavy?

I need to create something like this http://cph2010.drupal.org/sessions/timetable.html and the way I would like to create it is this http://groups.drupal.org/node/2567 with this dript style.

Does anyone know the right way to create a timetable with drupal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simplification could be the following:

Create just one content type called **presentation** that has speaker, agenda, time, title, and company as fields (and anything else you want).

Then you create one view which lists nodes of type presentation.

- In the fields portion, you select all the fields you think are relevant to show in the table, perhaps just title and speaker.  The title can be a link to the full content.
- Perhaps have the style be 'grid' and order the items by 'time', so the ones in the same time slot are on the same row.

That's one idea to make it simpler.  Does it work in your case?

Comment: Hi Bonaria, Thanks but the problem is that I need to have speaker, company and agenda such as different content type. I cannot have it all together because the have Pictures, bio, jobtitle, website, logo, company description, activities(related to other content type) and other fields.

Comment: Ah ok.  You know, you can still use one view by using relationships and pulling fields from nodes that are referenced (such as the speaker fields, agenda fields, etc).  That would simplify things.  Is your way working, and you're just wondering whether you can simplify or are you not quite getting what you want with your approach?

Comment: I'm wondering on how I can simplify the code. I'm getting what I want, i'm just thinking about the performance... One view is not good, because there are other static row in the middle, like lunch, opening, closing etc.. Thanks anyway Boriana...